# fortran 77 conflicting types in external

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I'm working with a F77 code, and I am encountering a problem in the compilation. I think I've narrowed down the problem but don't know a straight forward way of fixing it.

The code is extremely long so I'll try to be as clear as possible with the little snippets I use.

The error is the following:

```
/tmp/fort77-4812-1.c:2728:12: error: conflicting types for ‘func_’
doublereal func_(doublereal *e)

/tmp/fort77-4812-1.c:272:43:
```

> note: previous declaration of ‘func1_’ was here

```
extern /* Subroutine */ int func1_(), func2_();
                                       ^
```

where func(n) is some function. This happens with both func1 and func2 and they both have the same format, they differ in arithmetic.

The code starts like this:

```
Implicit double precision(a-h,o-z)
...
//initialization of some Arrays & parameters
...
external func1,func2
...
...
...

function func1(n)
implicit double precision(a-h,o-z)
...
...
end
```

I think the external is trying to keep the function as int but it is defined as a realdouble because of the implicit double.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal example? Please make sure that the `external` functions are really external, and not defined in the same scope.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an error caused by your choice of compiler, which I am assuming is `f2c`, which is a language translator.  The problem is the translation is not handling the `external` attribute declaration properly and is producing a C language variable declaration which is not respecting your implicit typing rules (which appears to be a bug I cannot reproduce with f2c version 20060506).

I recommend using a proper Fortran compiler instead of `f2c`.

Comment: I am using F77 to compile.

Comment: @Gio what is the output of `F77 -v`.  The creation of c language temporary files is something only `f2c` does, and your `F77` is probably just a symlink to that compiler.

Comment: @Gio you should install a different Fortran compiler.  Gfortran isn't technically a F77 compiler but it can most likely compile whatever you have.